# Collecting values from views BEFORE POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view that allows data entry for submission to the database.  In the process of entering data in this view, the requirement is that I link to another view, select a particular row of data, then return with said data to the original view without losing any of the previous edits in the original view.

I am using  @Html.ActionLink() to get to the other view and the same sort of link to return to view 1.  I've attempted session, TempData, etc. and all entries are lost, I believe, due to not actually doing a form post.

These two views are managed by two separate controllers.

Comment: make that other view as a partial view and renders it inside the view that you are entering data with. Don't break the stateless model

Comment: yes it's because you don't post back. Nothing to stop you replacing your actionlink with a button which _does_ post back, and then stores the data in the session, and redirects to the other view, and then vice-versa back in the other direction. But as Steve says, using ajax and partial views would probably be less messy and also give a better user experience.

Comment: Thanks.  I am relatively new to MVC and some of what does and does not go on behind a view is somewhat confusing, at times.  I appreciate the validation that, at least, I was seeing what I was seeing.